# Duvida sobre implementação de Lazy Load e Dependency Injection

Tags: c#, asp.net, design-pattern, injeção-de-dependência, lazy-loading

O cenário é simples, tem uma classe PessoaFisica que possui vinculada a ela uma lista de Contatos (instancias de pessoas fisicas), Telefones (instancias de uma entidade Telefone) e uma lista de Endereços (instâncias de uma entidade Endereço).

Tenho no projeto atual as camadas padrão: DAO, BusinessLayer e Gui, só que a Gui acessa as camadas abaixo por uma Facade. Uso Singleton para instanciar a Facade, pois ela mantem as instâncias dos layers de negócios e dos repositórios.

Estou planejando uma refatoração porque atualmente o repositório da classe PessoaFisica carrega todas as informações quando eu mando carregar/localizar uma pessoaFisica no banco, mesmo que eu não vá usar os dados dos contatos, endereços, etc.

Então, pretendo usar lazy load para melhorar a performance, mas, estou com dúvidas em como fazer a injeção de dependência da melhor forma.

Como já tenho uma interface para o repositorio, estou pensando em usar uma factory que entrega as implementações adequadas dos repositórios e singleton para evitar ter mais de uma instancia, seja qual for a parte do aplicativo.

Os repositórios para os endereços seriam passados via construtor para a classe PessoaFisica, mas, gostaria de não obrigar o usuário da classe PessoaFisica a instânciar os repositorios e abstrair essa responsabilidade sem comprometer os padrões de projeto, alguma idéia?

Já tenho os testes unitários para os metodos dos repositorios, o que facilita muito a refatoração.

O projeto é web, com asp.net e c# e uso ADO.NET.

Acham que é o melhor caminho? Sugestões?

Comment: O que exatamente você está usando na camada de dados? Algum framework? Você implementou a camada usando código seu? Existem frameworks que já realizam este trabalho por você.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez eu estou implementando tudo na mão, não uso nenhum framework (entity, etc). Foi uma questão de integridade conceitual, o projeto já tinha código legado (.net 2.0) e escolhi continuar mantendo o padrão para não ter que refatorar tudo e para evitar ficar com componentes da mesma camada implementados com ferramentas diferentes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se a ideia é injeção de dependências, o ideal para a sua implementação é usar um Proxy Dinâmico. [O melhor link que eu conheço como introdução é este](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13353/Using-Attributes-and-RealProxy-to-perform-property).

Como você já possui as interfaces, a melhor maneira de carregar o objeto é quando ele é efetivamente acessado. Não é a Façade que tem que determinar isso. Então o que pode ser feito é colocar no lugar dos objetos relacionados um objeto que finja ser outro.

### E como é isso?

O Proxy Dinâmico finge que é o objeto que possui os dados. Ao ser acessado, um interceptador vai até a camada de dados e troca o objeto de proxy pelo objeto verdadeiro, que contém os dados de fato.

Esta forma é utilizada pelo Entity Framework e Active Record, dois dos frameworks mais populares de mapeamento objeto-relacional utilizados até o momento.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, vou dar uma pesquisada sobre o proxy dinâmico e dou um feedback. Na verdade, não planejava usar a facade para gerenciar isso, ela apenas encapsula as chamadas com polimofismo e garante que nao tenho mais instâncias do que preciso com singleton, assim que terminar a pesquisa sobre o proxy eu dou um retorno. Valeu

Comment: Velho, dei uma olhada no link que você me passou e fui atras do meu bom e velho GOF e tava la a resposta, vou ter que fazer mais algumas alterações nos metodos de carga para poder encapsular tudo que preciso e controlar via proxy, mas, serão correções estruturais que vão melhorar o codigo, resumindo, vou aplicar o proxy mesmo :) (resposta marcada) valeu